# Redis MGET Limitations

Tags: redis

We're planning to use MGET for one of our Systems. During benchmarking, we were able to retrieve values for 1 Million Keys in one MGET call in lettuce and were quite surprised.

What I've been trying to find are the limitations of MGET. Specifically,

1. Is there any limit to number of Keys that can be retrieved in one MGET call?
2. Is there any limit to size of data that gets returned by a single MGET call?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Is there any limit to number of Keys that can be retrieved in one MGET call?

Theoretically, the limit is the max value for int: 0x7FFFFFFF. However, in practice, you CANNOT have so many keys in a single Redis instance (it costs too much memory).

> Is there any limit to size of data that gets returned by a single MGET call?

Theoretically, NO limit. However, in practice, Redis saves the returned values in memory before sending to client, so if you try to `MGET` too many keys, you'll get OOM problem.

In a word, **it's a bad idea to `MGET` too many keys from Redis**: it costs too much memory, and blocks Redis for a long time.